# How to update React setState immediately

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state, use-effect, setstate

I'm calling AddItemToList() on "onClick" event.
However, since setTotalExpensesAmount() is asynchronous, it's called too late and axios.post() sends incorrect value of totalExpenses to the database (previous one).

I believe, using useEffect() outside AddItemToList() function is not a correct solution.

Should I make axios.post() the callback of setTotalExpensesAmount()? If so, how can I do it?

```
const AddItemToList = () => {
        if (Expense !== '' && Amount !== '' && Number(Amount) > 0) {
            setExpenseAndAmountList(
                [
                    ...expenseAndAmountList, 
                    { 
                        expenseTitle: Expense,
                        expenseAmount: Amount,
                        id: Math.random() * 1000
                    }
                ]
            );

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/insertedExpenseAndAmount', 
            {
                expenseTitle: Expense,
                expenseAmount: Amount
            });
            
            setTotalExpensesAmount((currentTotalExpenses: number) => currentTotalExpenses + Number(Amount));

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/totalexpensesamount', 
            {
                totalExpensesAmount: totalExpenses
            });
            
            setExpense("");
            setAmount("");
            setIfNotValidInputs(false);
            setTotalBalance(Number(income) - totalExpenses);
        } else {
            setIfNotValidInputs(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can set the AddItemToList() as an async function and then wait (using the await keyword) for setTotalExpensesAmount to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this.

1. You can calculate the `newTotalExpense` and do `setTotalExpense` with the new value. Also, pass the `newTotalExpense` in the post call you are making.

```
    const AddItemToList = () => {
        if (Expense !== '' && Amount !== '' && Number(Amount) > 0) {
            setExpenseAndAmountList(
                [
                    ...expenseAndAmountList, 
                    { 
                        expenseTitle: Expense,
                        expenseAmount: Amount,
                        id: Math.random() * 1000
                    }
                ]
            );

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/insertedExpenseAndAmount', 
            {
                expenseTitle: Expense,
                expenseAmount: Amount
            });

            const newTotalExpense = currentTotalExpenses + Number(Amount)
            setTotalExpensesAmount(newTotalExpense);

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/totalexpensesamount', 
            {
                totalExpensesAmount: newTotalExpense
            });
            
            setExpense("");
            setAmount("");
            setIfNotValidInputs(false);
            setTotalBalance(Number(income) - totalExpenses);
        } else {
            setIfNotValidInputs(true);
        }
    }
```

2. You can use `useEffect` hook which will trigger on the change of `totalExpense` value. You can make the post call inside the `useEffect`.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/totalexpensesamount', 
        {
            totalExpensesAmount: totalExpenses
        });        
    }, [totalExpense])
    
    const AddItemToList = () => {
        if (Expense !== '' && Amount !== '' && Number(Amount) > 0) {
            setExpenseAndAmountList(
                [
                    ...expenseAndAmountList, 
                    { 
                        expenseTitle: Expense,
                        expenseAmount: Amount,
                        id: Math.random() * 1000
                    }
                ]
            );

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/insertedExpenseAndAmount', 
            {
                expenseTitle: Expense,
                expenseAmount: Amount
            });
            
            setTotalExpensesAmount((currentTotalExpenses: number) => currentTotalExpenses + Number(Amount));

            setExpense("");
            setAmount("");
            setIfNotValidInputs(false);
            setTotalBalance(Number(income) - totalExpenses);
        } else {
            setIfNotValidInputs(true);
        }
    }
```